# Optimize functions in jQueryUI

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I want to optimized some codes (I use jQuery UI):

```
$(function() {
    $('.click-login-modal').click(function() {
        $('.login-modal').dialog('open');
        return false;
    })

    $('.login-modal').dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        width: 500,
        height:300,
        modal: true,
        resizable: false,
    })
    $('.click-register-modal').click(function() {
        $('.register-modal').dialog('open');
        return false;
    })

    $('.register-modal').dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        width: 500,
        height:300,
        modal: true,
        resizable: false,
    })
})
```

It's possible? I have two deferential modals. (Dialog Popup)

Answer (score 3):

```
var options = {
        autoOpen: false,
        width: 500,
        height:300,
        modal: true,
        resizable: false
    };

$(".register-modal").dialog(options);
$(".login-modal").dialog(options);

$('.click-register-modal, .click-login-modal').click(function() {
    $(this).dialog('open');
    return false;
});
```

Comment: ie will have a fit with the closing comma!

Comment: thanks, I think `$('.register-modal').dialog('open');` should be `$('.login-modal, .register-modal').dialog('open');`

Comment: @Mini - actually, it should be `$(this).dialog('open');`. Updated.

Comment: Opps. the optimized open two modals in the same time. why?

Comment: Argh! I guess they have to be bound one at a time.

Comment: Still one error karim, `'.click-register-modal'` should open `'.register-model'` in the handler, not `this`.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the tabs approach, where the `href` would point to the element ID, so you can change your modal classes to IDs and then use:

```
var options = {
        autoOpen: false,
        width: 500,
        height:300,
        modal: true,
        resizable: false
    };

$(".register-modal").dialog(options);
$(".login-modal").dialog(options);

$('.click-register-modal, .click-login-modal').click(function() {
    $($(this).attr('href')).dialog('open');
    return false;
});
```

Or if you need to use classes then replace the hash `#` with a dot `.` also if you are not using LINKS you may use the `rel` attribute to point to your dialogs or even jquery [`data`](http://api.jquery.com/data/).